# .join() error; Not sure why

Tags: python

Since I don't want an array's indices to be separated by a comma, I wrote this code:

```
landscape2 = ''.join(landscape)
```

However, I got an error message saying "landscape2 = ''.join(landscape)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found"
I don't know what this means, and I wondered if you could help.

Comment: It means at least one element is a list inside your list i.e `[["foo"]]`, if you want to also join what is inside the lists,you want something like  `landscape2 = ''.join(map("".join,landscape))`. If you posted your code and the error it would be a lot  easier to diagnose

Comment: Show what landscape is

Comment: landscape = [['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,X'] ,['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'] ,['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'] ,['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'] ,['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'] ,['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'] ,['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'] ,['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'] ,['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'] ,['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'] ,['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'] ,['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'] ,['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'] ,['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-'] ,['O,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']]

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Yep, you want what I suggested above, if you want each on a newline use `"\n"` for the outer join, if you want one long line leave it as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you described means it's trying to join two lists together. That's not possible.

Based on your comment, it sounds like what you ACTUALLY want to do is:

```
"\n".join(["".join(sublst) for sublst in landscape])
```

This will create a new list of strings, then join those strings with newlines, essentially creating a 2D rectangle of characters.

Comment: you can remove the list comprehension, it will just use generator comprehension instead

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, that is less efficient than using a  list

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen see the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245792/when-is-not-a-good-time-to-use-python-generators). It's over a year old, but I haven't seen any evidence that it's changed (admittedly I haven't profiled it in *forever*)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen essentially, `str.join` likes lists, since it has two make two passes anyway.