# Is there a way to use the String replace() Method to replace anything

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, methods

Something like

`sentence.replace(*, "newword")`

(which doesn't work, btw)

Let's say

`sentence = "hello world"
return sentence.replace(*, "newworld")`

should return "newword newword"

Comment: What would `sentence.replace(*, "newword")` return?

Comment: let's say `sentence = "hello world"`, then it should return `sentence = "newword newword"`

Comment: Try `sentence = ' '.join(['newword'] * len(sentence.split()))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you aren't going to be replacing a specific word, [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) won't really support any kind of pattern-matching.

However, you could use the [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function that will allow you to pass in a Regular Expression that would match everything and replace it :

```
import re
# Replace each series of non-space characters [^\s]+ with "newword"
sentence = re.sub('[^\s]+','newword',sentence)
```

**Example**

You can find a [complete interactive example of this here](http://ideone.com/f1aKJW) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Silly fingers. Thanks, I've adjusted it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a word replace. So instead of string.replace which replaces characters, you want something that will replace all words.

```
>>> sentence = "hello world this is my sentence"
>>> " ".join(["newword"] * len(sentence.split()))
'newword newword newword newword newword newword'
```

In the above case we're spiting the sentence into a list of it's words and simple making another list of words "newword" of the same length. Finally we're joining the new words together with the " " character in between them

Answer (score 0):

If you care about speed, just crafting the string manually seems to be twice as fast:

```
In [8]: import re

In [9]: sentence = "hello world this is my sentence"

In [10]: nonspace = re.compile('[^\s]+')

In [11]: %timeit re.sub(nonspace, 'newword', sentence)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.28 µs per loop

In [12]: %timeit ' '.join('newword' for _ in xrange(len(sentence.split())))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.52 µs per loop

In [13]: sentence *= 40  # Make the sentence longer

In [14]: %timeit re.sub(nonspace, 'newword', sentence)
10000 loops, best of 3: 70.6 µs per loop

In [15]: %timeit ' '.join('newword' for _ in xrange(len(sentence.split())))
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.2 µs per loop
```

And `join` is actually [faster when you hand it a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26635939/2980246), so `' '.join(['newword' for _ in xrange(len(sentence.split()))])` should result in some performance improvements (it caches the result in my informal `%timeit` tests, so I didn't include it)

Comment: Thank you, jayelm!