# What are python generators?

Tags: python, generator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can you use Python generator functions for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102535/what-can-you-use-python-generator-functions-for)

I tried to read about python generators but did not understand much about the concept as to what we can do with generators, I am new to python

please let me know
Thank you

Comment: You should start with coroutines & continuations to learn general ideas behind generators. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presentation here explains generators very well:

http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/index.html

I have yet to find a use for the more advanced pipelining stuff, but I use the general technique all the time to parse logfiles.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, a generator in Python is a function that can maintain state between values produced. Read [this](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/).

Answer (score 1):

While Yassin's answer is completely correct, I would rather explain it differently: A generator is a function that returns multiple values over time, where each value is generated (and returned) when you ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators Read this first.

Basically, generators are iterable objects. The magic word here is **yield**.
Instead of using the return statement, you use yield, which doesn't stop the execution of a function, but returns something. In order for you to be able to consume what the generator returns, you have to iterate through it.