# if item in list exists: do stuff

Tags: python, regex, indexing

Suppose I have the list, which I have edited so it's not just called "list" anymore

```
my_list = ['a b', 'b c d e', 'c', 'd e f g h', 'e f g h i j', 'f g h', 'g h']
```

I am trying to examine a specific element in the list, and see if one of the elements contains a certain string. I've been using something along the lines of the code below:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    splitList = my_list[i].split(' ')
    if splitList[3] == "c":
        print "True"
    else:
        print "False"
```

but what I really want to do is check to see if splitList[3] even exists, and if it does, if  it == "c" or simply print the 3rd "thing" in the element. (I'm being generic in my question, but my actual data is looking for a specific 3 character string)  I'm certain regular expressions would solve all my problems but I've been looking for the perfect regex solution for days and am overwhelmed and without a solution. My data is very predictable and and I just need to check if the second word in an element of a list is there or not.

**Is there a simple pythonic way to check to see if the a list even HAS something at a specific index, and if it does to go on from there?**

---

If you want to suggest a regex solution,
the 24th element in my list is always 
"G# Abc"   '#' can be 1-12 inclusive
and then the 25th element may also be
" G# Abc"   with '#' as 1-12
if the 25th element is not in the format " G# Abc", then the element and any other elements is not relevant. If it is in the format " G# Abc", I need to add the number to a new list.

Comment: Just so you know, you can iterate over a list directly.. no need to get its length, build a range, then access each via index.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you are asking as far as the checking of the 3rd element and all that, but the loop itself can be simplified: for i in l: splitList = i.split()

Comment: @wagras don't use `list` as a variable name as it is already a builtin function you will hide

Comment: To clarify @jdi, you (almost) never do `for i in range(len(my_list))`. Either do `for elt in my_list` or -- if you need the index -- `for i, elt in enumerate(my_list)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, everyone. and I shan't be using "list" as my list name any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given an arbitrary string `'x y z'`, split into a list `['x', 'y', 'z']` with `'x y z'.split()`, the simple pythonic way to test whether an index exists is `len`. Modifying your code above slightly:

```
# don't use `list` as a variable name; it masks the built-in `list` constructor
str_list = ['a b', 'b c d e', 'c', 'd e f g h', 'e f g h i j', 'f g h', 'g h']
for s in str_list:
    split_list = s.split(' ')
    if len(split_list) > 3 and split_list[3] == 'c':
        print "True"
    else:
        print "False"
```

Comment: @katrielalex what does "EAFP" mean?

Comment: [It's Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp): It's one of the Python programming style conventions. It means that instead of checking whether something is OK to do, you do it and catch the exception if it wasn't.

Comment: This works perfectly. I've never successfully used and 'if' statement with an 'and.' Not so complicated.  Thank you.

Comment: @katrielalex, it's not always easier. Catching an exception is expensive; `try`/`except` should only be used when it's likely that the `try` block will succeed. In other words, `except` is for exceptional cases. If both cases are equally likely, `if` will be much faster.

Comment: @katrielalex, IYI, I saw a blog post a while ago with some pretty revealing timings, but couldn't find it again. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3111386/577088) by Alex Martelli is less thorough, but gets the point across pretty well nonetheless.

Answer (score 7):

> [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

```
relevant_elements = set()
for values in my_list:
    try:
        elt = values.split()[3]
    except IndexError:
        continue
    else:
        if is_correct_format(elt):
            relevant_elements.add(elt)
```

Comment: Hah. I hate to have to comment again, but dicts dont have an `add()` method ;-)

Comment: @jdi oops, too much maths. Thanks.

Comment: The reason I didn't "accept" this answer was simply because I don't understand it well enough to feel comfortable implementing it. The thg453's answer is at my level so I used it, although this seems more elegant.

Answer (score 4):

Use the power of functional programming.

With Python2:

```
from itertools import imap
for i in (x[3] for x in imap(str.split, input_strings) if len(x) >= 4):
     print i
```

With Python3:

```
for i in (x[3] for x in map(str.split, input_strings) if len(x) >= 4):
     print(i)
```

(Mentioned by [@thg435](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/): "you could use `from future_builtins import map` and `from __future__ import print_function` to make py2 solution identical to py3.")

Explanation:

- [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is a function, that splits the input at (runs of) whitespace characters.
- [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) resp. [`imap`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) applies it to all members of the list. Both function generate a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795656/what-are-python-generators).
- The `if len(x) >= 4` tests if a fourth item (located at index 3) exists.
- The `(x[3] for x in ... if ...)` generates a generator, that takes the fourth element of the split string list.

Comment: I'd hate to say this but the code here is just hideous. I absolutely LOVE FP. But there is no way any beginner can look at those two lines and without thinking about it for 10 ~ minutes, decode what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: <obligatory `itertools.imap` in Python 2.x remark> (EDIT: That is, `map` is inefficient in Python 2.x and you should use `imap` instead. It's fine in Python 3.x)

Comment: @katrielalex I am here to learn, thanks for mentioning `imap`!

Comment: The downvote was by me. I removed it now, as it looks a bit better, but I'd still recommend you to do 1 thing and only 1 thing per line.

You don't need to save lines of code you know, the rainforest will be saved by saving paper :-)

Comment: Just two more nitpicks: you could use `from future_builtins import map` and `from __future__ import print_function` to make py2 solution identical to py3. And don't call a list `list`.

Comment: @thg435 I woundn't have called it `list` if the wasn't the name OP gave it. I really don't like `from __future__`. It feels like a hack. :-/

Comment: @thg435 gotta admit that you are right: calling it `list` makes it awful to understand.