# Clicking a link based on partial text match

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium 2/Webdriver with python and I want to click on the first link that starts with a string. Here's the code I came up with:

```
def click_link_partial(div_id, partial):
  linkdiv = driver.find_element_by_id(div_id)
  z = (a.click() for a in linkdiv.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') if a.text.startswith(partial))
  z.next()
```

I'm not very familiar with generators in Python. Why isn't a.click() called immediately, instead of when z.next() executes?

Are there any drawbacks to using this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, please, familiarize yourself with Python's generators, they are a very powerful tool in your Python arsenal. A great explanation by Thomas Wouters can be found by reading another question: [What can you use Python generator functions for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102535/what-can-you-use-python-generator-functions-for)

Once you're finished reading, you'll realize that a generator just gives you the ability to evaluate expressions lazily.

Relating this piece of information to your code above, you will find that `a.click()` will not actually execute right away, because it is expected that you iterate over the generator expression, which is what you've created. This is why you must issue `z.next()` to actually invoke the `click()` method.

If you do not want to issue a `z.next()`, and assuming you just want to click the first partially matched link, you would re-write your code above as follows:

```
def click_link_partial(div_id, partial):
  linkdiv = driver.find_element_by_id(div_id)
  for a in linkdiv.find_elements_by_tag_name('a'):
      if a.text.startswith(partial):
         a.click()
         break  # stop iterating over the partially matched elements.
```

However, if you want to click on all the partially linked elements, then you should remove the `z.next()` from your code above and return the generator expression to be used in an outer function/method. Here's an example:

```
def click_link_partial(div_id, partial):
  linkdiv = driver.find_element_by_id(div_id)
  return (a for a in linkdiv.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') 
            if a.text.startswith(partial))

for matched_clickable_anchor in click_link_partial('#some-div-id', 'spam'):
    matched_clickable_anchor.click()  # do click
    # do something else.
```

Hope this helps!