# Why call clearup code in generator function?

Tags: python, frameworks, wsgi, web.py

guys. I'm reading web.py source code to understand how WSGI frameworks work.

When reading application.py module, I wonder why call self._cleanup in cleanup which is a generator function.

I searched reasons to use generator, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102535/what-can-you-use-python-generator-functions-for), but I'm not sure why use generator here.

Here is the code block:

```
def wsgi(env, start_resp):
    # clear threadlocal to avoid inteference of previous requests
    self._cleanup()

    self.load(env)
    try:
        # allow uppercase methods only
        if web.ctx.method.upper() != web.ctx.method:
            raise web.nomethod()

        result = self.handle_with_processors()
        if is_generator(result):
            result = peep(result)
        else:
            result = [result]
    except web.HTTPError, e:
        result = [e.data]

    result = web.utf8(iter(result))

    status, headers = web.ctx.status, web.ctx.headers
    start_resp(status, headers)

    def cleanup():
        self._cleanup()
        yield '' # force this function to be a generator

    return itertools.chain(result, cleanup())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `itertools.chain(result, cleanup())` does is effectively

```
def wsgi(env, start_resp):
    [...]

    status, headers = web.ctx.status, web.ctx.headers
    start_resp(status, headers)

    for part in result:
         yield part
    self._cleanup()
    # yield '' # you'd skip this line because it's pointless
```

The only reason I can imagine why it's written in such a weird way is to avoid that extra pure Python loop for a little bit of performance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's reasonable. I rethink about the code, another reason I guess is returning result to client as soon as possible, then do cleanup job at last to avoid the delay. Not sure whether it's right.