# python delayed execution

Tags: python, perl, lisp, sicp

To implement [streams as delayed lists](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node70.html) in Lisp it's [recommended](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2007/11/05/sicp-sections-351-352/) to use Lisp macros.

```
(defmacro cons-stream (a b)
   (cons ,a (delay ,b)))

(defmacro delay (expr)
  `(memo-proc (lambda () ,expr)))
```

What would by Python and Perl way to do the same thing?

EDIT. Is it possible to use such a cool construct as streams

```
(define primes (sieve (integers-starting-from 2)))
```

in languages like Python and Perl

Comment: Python uses [generators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) to do this kind of thing.

Comment: There's not much special about it in Lisp (except for the use of macro, of course), but it is *not* the same as iterators or as generators.  They can be used sometimes to implement similar solutions, but they have a very different interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Perl

[runrig suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497816/python-delayed-execution/6497929#6497929) the techniques from Mark Dominus's excellent [*Higher Order Perl*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497816/python-delayed-execution/6497929#6497929). Using the [Stream module](http://hop.perl.plover.com/Examples/ALL/Stream.pm) from HOP's freely available sample code, the sieve of Eratosthenes is

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Stream qw/ filter head node promise show tail upfrom /;

use subs 'sieve';  # no parens on recursive calls
sub sieve {
  my($s) = @_;
  my $n = head $s;
  node $n, promise { sieve filter { $_[0] % $n != 0 } tail $s };
}

sub primes { sieve upfrom 2 }

show primes, 10;
```

Output:

```
$ ./primes
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29
```

### Python

Borrowing code from a [gist by alexbowe](https://gist.github.com/938886), the sieve in Python using streams is

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

null_stream = (None, None)

def reduce(f, result, stream):
    if stream is null_stream: return result
    return reduce(f, f(result, head(stream)), tail(stream))

def take(N, stream):
    if N <= 0 or stream is null_stream: return null_stream
    return (head(stream), lambda: take(N-1, tail(stream)))

def filter(pred, stream):
    if stream is null_stream: return null_stream
    if pred(head(stream)):
        return (head(stream), lambda: filter(pred, tail(stream)))
    return filter(pred, tail(stream))

def integers_from(N): return (N, lambda: integers_from(N+1))
def head((H, _)): return H
def tail((_, T)): return T()
def to_array(stream): return reduce(lambda a, x: a + [x], [], stream)

def sieve(stream):
    if stream is null_stream: return null_stream
    h = head(stream)
    return (h, lambda: sieve(filter(lambda x: x%h != 0, tail(stream))))

def primes(): return sieve(integers_from(2))

print to_array(take(10, primes()))
```

Output:

```
$ ./prymes 
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

### Other possibilities

In some languages, the stream pattern is invisible. Lazy evaluation is a feature of Haskell, for instance, so you could define `primes` as

```
primes = sieve [2 ..]
  where sieve (x:xs) =
          let remains = filter (not . isMultipleOf x) xs
          in x : sieve remains
        isMultipleOf a b = b `mod` a == 0
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python, the closest structure would probably be a generator expression.

In Perl, there is not a native lazy list, but the language provides all of the primitives that are needed to build one.  I have written a lazy list library called [List::Gen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aGen) which is available on CPAN.

```
use List::Gen '*';

my $primes = <2..>->filter(\&is_prime);  # where you provide &is_prime

say "@$primes[0..10]";  # lazily finds the first 11 primes
```

the `<2..>` bit could be written verbosely as `range(2, 9**9**9)`

Answer (score 3):

In perl you would use anonymous subroutines (like LISP's lambda). There are plenty of examples in [chapter 6](http://hop.perl.plover.com/chap06.html) of [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Although it's hard to tell what you *actually* want, since many things are subtly different between the different languages, he Python equivalent you're looking for is probably a *generator*, which is a kind of function that can be asked to produce the next value and then suspends itself. They were previously covered in (for example) [What can you use Python generator functions for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102535/what-can-you-use-python-generator-functions-for), and there are lots of examples and tutorials of them available elsewhere -- for example, http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/index.html

Comment: No! -- generators are *different* than lazy lists.  The main difference is that they provide a functional interface whereas a generator is limited to just getting the current result.

Comment: Yes, different things in different languages are different.

Comment: These are different features, period.  Not just some generic "different things look different".  In other words, this is not an answer to the question.  It's probably easy to create lazy lists in Python -- and the result would indeed look different than in Lisp, but it would not be generators.  (Here's a hint: implementing generators require low-level support like grabbing a continuation; implementing lazy lists requires just first class functions.)