# Iterate on two lists and sync them

Tags: python, iteration

I need to iterate on two lists in the following way:

Pseudo code:

```
j=1
for i=1 to n:
   print a[i], b[j]
   while b[j+1] <= a[i]:
      j++
      print a[i], b[j]
```

For example:

```
a = [1 3 5 7]
b = [2 4 9]
```

Desired output:

```
1 2
3 2
5 2
5 4
7 4
```

How do you do it cleanly in python?

Comment: The question seems incomplete to me, can you explain your output based on the two input lists? What happened to the `9`?

Comment: @Levon the `9` doesn't show up in the output of the pseudocode, as my translated Python shows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your pseudo code will almost work in Python. Some working code that does what you want is:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 7]
b = [2, 4, 9] 
j = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    print a[i], b[j]
    while j<len(b)-1 and b[j+1] <= a[i]:
        j += 1
        print a[i], b[j]
```

Note the few changes to make it work in Python:

1. When declaring the list, commas are required between items.
2. List indices start at 0, so both `i` and `j` should start there.
3. `len(a)` returns the length of `a` (4 in this case), and iterating `i` through `range(len(a))` executes the loop for each integer from `0` to `len(a)-1`, which is all of the indices in `a`.
4. The `++` operation is not supported in Python, so we use `j +=1` instead.
5. We have to avoid using out of bounds indices of `b`, so we test to make sure `j` will be in bounds before incrementing it.

This code can be made more pythonic by iterating through the list as follows:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 7]
b = [2, 4, 9] 
j = 0
for element in a:
   print element, b[j]
   while j<len(b)-1 and b[j+1] <= element:
      j += 1
      print element, b[j]
```

In general, you probably don't want to just print list elements, so for a more general use case you can create a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102535/what-can-you-use-python-generator-functions-for), like:

```
def sync_lists(a, b)
    if b:
        j = 0
        for element in a:
            yield (element, b[j])
            while j<len(b)-1 and b[j+1] <= element:
                j += 1
                yield (element, b[j])
```

And then you can print them as before with

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 7]
b = [2, 4, 9]
for (e1, e2) in sync_lists(a, b):
    print e1, e2
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems just unusual enough that a direct translation of the pseudocode is probably simpler than some games with `next` and `itertools`.  I might wrap up this iteration logic in a generator, though, which seems to me the most Pythonic "home" for quirky iteration logics.

Comment: I'm curious -- you recommend using `enumerate`, but it doesn't look like you're using `i`.  Wouldn't it be easier just to iterate over the list?

Comment: @SamMussmann you're right, I missed that. For some reason I thought I still needed the index into `a`.

Answer (score 2):

The generator code in [murgatroid99's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832874/279627) can be generalised to any iterables (as opposed to sequences only) by using `next()` instead of index arithmetic:

```
def sync_list(a, b):
    b = iter(b)
    y, next_y = next(b), next(b)
    for x in a:
       yield x, y
       while next_y <= x:
          y, next_y = next_y, next(b)
          yield x, y
```

Comment: Note that with the wrong arrays, you might start getting `StopIteration` exceptions. I modified my code to avoid the corresponding `IndexError`s.

Comment: @murgatroid99: `StopIteration` is handled by a caller e.g., a for-loop. No special handling is required in the generator for "wrong" arrays.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian but `b` is not being iterated through in a for-loop, so the caller *is* `sync_list`. Calling [`next`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next) can raise that exception, and using it in a loop doesn't magically handle it.

Comment: @murgatroid99: If `StopIteration` is raised inside a generator, this terminates the generator.  I think this is the more reasonable behaviour than breaking the invariants (which is what your new code does in case `b` is too short).

Comment: @murgatroid99: The example caller is `for e1, e2 in sync_lists(a, b):`. It handles `StopIteration` transparently

Comment: @SvenMarnach since no invariants were given, I can't comment on whether my code breaks them, but I see you are right about the exception.

Comment: @murgatroid99: I interpreted `y <= x` for all yielded pairs as the desired invariant, but you are right that this hasn't been clearly specified (and none of the suggested code snippets checks this for the first pair).