# generator vs. list comprehension

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

I have something, when run as a *list comprehension*, runs fine.

It looks like,

```
[myClass().Function(things) for things in biggerThing]
```

`Function` is a method, and it builds a list. The method itself doesn't return anything, but lists get manipulated within.

Now when I change it to a *generator* ,

```
(myClass().Function(things) for things in biggerThing)
```

It doesn't manipulate the data like I would expect it to. In fact, it doesn't seem to manipulate it at all.

What is the functional difference between a *list comprehension* and a *generator*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension for the side effects. Now you are building a list of `None` values and discarding it again, wasting CPU and memory.

Comment: Why are you using a list comprehension if you don't want to build a list? Usually people learn about `for` loops before they learn about list comprehensions, but maybe you went the other way?

Answer (score 5):

Generators are evaluated on the fly, as they are consumed. So if you never iterate over a generator, its elements are never evaluated.

So, if you did:

```
for _ in (myClass().Function(things) for things in biggerThing):
    pass
```

`Function` would run.

---

Now, your intent really isn't clear here.

Instead, consider using `map`:

```
map(myClass().Function, biggerThing)
```

Note that this will always use the same instance of MyClass

If that's a problem, then do:

```
for things in BiggerThing:
    myClass().Function(things)
```

Comment: I don't think `map` would be a better solution than a generator or a list comprehension. If you don't care about the return value of `myClass().Function(things)`, there is no reason to waste memory by storing the results.

Comment: The regular for loop is how I had it structure before. And I was just wondering if by using a generator if it might speed up the program execution.

Comment: @Blender I was essentially pointing out that the intent would be clearer using map. Now, if performance is a concern, a for loop is probably the most appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Generators are [lazy evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/102632/1265154). You need to process a generator in order to your function be evaluated. One can use [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) to consume a generator:

```
import collections
generator = (myClass().Function(thing) for thing in biggerThing) 
collections.deque(generator , maxlen=0)
```

And consider using `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`, or change to

```
myfunc = myClass().Function
generator = (myfunc(thing) for thing in biggerThing) 
collections.deque(generator , maxlen=0)
```

to reduce new instance of `myClass` creation for each `thing` processing.

**update, performance**

1. `collections` vs `iteration`

```
def l():
    for x in range(100):
       y = x**2
      yield y

def consume(it):
    for i in it:
        pass

>>> timeit.timeit('from __main__ import l, consume; consume(l())', number=10000)
0.4535369873046875
>>> timeit.timeit('from __main__ import l, collections; collections.deque(l(), 0)', number=10000)
0.24533605575561523
```

2. instance vs class vs static methods

```
class Test(object):
    @staticmethod
    def stat_pow(x):
        return x**2
    @classmethod
    def class_pow(cls, x):
        return x**2
    def inst_pow(self, x):
        return x**2

def static_gen():
    for x in range(100):
        yield Test.stat_pow(x)

def class_gen():
    for x in range(100):
        yield Test.class_pow(x)

def inst_gen():
    for x in range(100):
        yield Test().inst_pow(x)

>>> timeit.timeit('from __main__ import static_gen as f, collections; collections.deque(f(), 0)', number=10000)
0.5983021259307861
>>> timeit.timeit('from __main__ import class_gen as f, collections; collections.deque(f(), 0)', number=10000)
0.6772890090942383
>>> timeit.timeit('from __main__ import inst_gen as f, collections; collections.deque(f(), 0)', number=10000)
0.8273470401763916
```

Comment: What are the performance benefits of using `collections.deque`?

Comment: `collections.deque` is probably the fastest way to consume a generator, but for this situation the overhead of instantiating your `myClass()` object to call one method on it and then throwing it way will almost certainly swamp any micro-optimisations.

Comment: @Duncan If you look at test results on my machine (bottom of this answer), in a simple case benefits of deque approach prevail that of myClass instaniation. It might be otherwise for more complex classes and functions, you might make your own tests.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your collect vs iteration times. Running your exact code I get 0.42 for `consume` and 0.43 for `dequeue`. I ran it several times and 'consume' is always slightly faster for me. Also, you aren't comparing like with like there. The comparison that should be made on the original code would be `collections.deque(generator , maxlen=0)` compared with just doing `for thing in biggerThing: myClass().Function(things)` Your comparison is forcing an extra for loop to consume a generator when the generator isn't needed at all.

Comment: @Duncan do you run cPython or PyPy or else? machine arch (64 or 32) and os?

Comment: That was Python 3.3.0, 32 bit on Windows 7. Just re-ran that and get 0.427 for `consume()` vs 0.431 for `dequeue()`. Running the identical code on Python 2.7.2 gave me 0.139 vs 0.143. Running on Pypy 1.7 is the only one where `deque` wins: 0.148 vs 0.105 on the first run, but if I repeat each `timeit` call I get 0.023 vs 0.030 for the second. Don't you just love a good JIT.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a generator, you are only able to use each element once. It's like I'm creating a batch of cookies that I'm eating as I go. They serve their purpose (make me happy), but they're gone once you use them.

List comprehensions create lists, and they will allow you to access that data structure forever (ostensibly). You can also use all the list methods on them (very useful). But the idea is that it creates an actual *data structure* (something that holds data for you).

Check out this post right here: [Generators vs. List Comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 1):

Generator won't execute the function, until you call `next()` on the generator.

```
 >>>def f():
 ...    print 'Hello'
 >>>l = [f() for _ in range(3)]
 Hello
 Hello
 Hello
 >>>g = (f() for _ in range(3)) # nothing happens 
 >>>
 >>>next(g)
 Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension:

- List can be indexed. 
  eg.,. `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4][0]`
- A created List can be used any number of times.
- An empty list occupies 72 bytes, and for each item adds occupies 8 bytes extra.

Generators:

- Generators cant be indexed
- A generator can be used only once.
- A generator occupies much lesser memory(80 bytes).

Please note that in case of generator, the content inside is emptied, once it is used.

```
>>> sys.getsizeof([])
72
>>> list1 = [x for x in range(0, 5)]
>>> sys.getsizeof(list1)
136
>>>
>>> generator1 = (x for x in range(0,100))
>>> sys.getsizeof(generator1)
80
>>> generator1 = (x for x in range(0,5))
>>> sys.getsizeof(generator1)
80
>>> list(generator1)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(generator1)
[]
>>>
```