# Python 2.7 if not any syntax?

Tags: list, python-2.7, if-statement, syntax

I just read a brilliant reply from [Sloth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142637/sloth) at [Remove lines that contain certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968998/remove-lines-that-contain-certain-string) question whilst searching for a way to filter out garbage lines in a txt / csv file.  The gist is "take x y z words/strings/whatever from input file, then filter through each line writing only the unfiltered lines."

The code he posted was:

```
bad_words = ['bad', 'naughty']

with open('oldfile.txt') as oldfile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
for line in oldfile:
    if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
        newfile.write(line)
```

My question is:  Would someone explain the line `if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):` ?

I tried just putting in `if not any(bad_word in line):` but it gave me an error.

I am trying to understand why.  A cursory search at python docs webpage didn't help me (I'm new to Python/programming and might not be too bright to boot :-) ).

Any references for me to read is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do Python's any and all functions work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490/how-do-pythons-any-and-all-functions-work)

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking that page.  You must be a quick reader, you replied almost immediately after I posted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Would someone explain the line `if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words)`

Sure.

`bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words` is what's called a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). It is very similar to a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), but more memory efficient.

```
if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
    newfile.write(line)
```

is basically equivalent to:

```
list1 = []
for bad_word in bad_words:
    if bad_word in line:
        list1.append(True)
    else:
        list1.append(False)

if not any(list1):
    newfile.write(line)
```

> I tried just putting in `if not any(bad_word in line):` but it gave me an error

Yeah, because [any](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) takes an *iterable* as input, and you have provided a boolean (`bad_word in line` evaluates to True or False, you can't iterate over it).

Try providing something you *can* iterate over, such as a list: `if not any([True, False, True]):`

Comment: Thank you very much for the hand holding.

Comment: "bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words"
is a generator not a list.

Comment: Is this what you mean?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933753/generator-vs-list-comprehension

Comment: "because `any` takes a list as input, and you have provided an iterator"... Incorrect, `bad_word in line` gives a boolean, not an iterator.

Comment: The code you provide is not equivalent, since any() is short-circuiting.