# Python list comprehension vs. nested loop, conciseness/efficiency

Tags: python, code-complexity

The following 2 methods do the same thing. Which one is more efficient in terms of time/space complexity?

```
** Method A**
for student in group.students:
    for grade in student.grades:
        some_operation(grade)

** Method B**
for grade in [grade for student in group.students for grade in student.grades]
    some_operation(grade)
```

Comment: B: consumes more memory because it builds an intermediate list. Use a generator expression instead: `for grade in (grade ...): some_operation(grade)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu,  "()" indicate generator? So the list of 'grades' won't be created as we loop thru it?

Comment: Related threads
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933753/generator-vs-list-comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method B looks weird and redundant. You could shorten it to:

```
[some_operation(grade) for student in group.students for grade in student.grades]
```

But method A is better either way because it doesn't create a list. Making a list simply to throw it away is confusing to the reader and wastes memory.

Comment: Agreed. Just don't like multiple levels of loops, because of my OCD. Any idea how to write concise yet equally efficient code in this case?

Comment: I strongly dislike this. list-comprehensions are expressions and should *not* be used to just calla function on a sequence of values. Besides: it consumes memory. If you have a scenario where you have millions of items on which to perform the action you probably don't want to create a useless list with million of elements.

Comment: No, do not shorten method B to a single list comprehension. Method B does not create a new list; the list comprehension creates one that you immediately discard.

Comment: Agreed with Alex and @Bakuiu list comprehension is inefficient in space.

Comment: @cheng shorter code is not necessarily cleaner or clearer. Always choose to write code that is instantly obvious to a reader rather than trying hard to save lines.

Comment: @Bakuriu yes but Method B already did that. I pointed out how to improve it but said it's still bad.

Comment: @chepner both versions of method B create a list and discard it immediately. My version has no disadvantage unless it is assigned to a variable.

Comment: A related question: nested loop vs generator expression, which one is more efficient?

Comment: @cheng if there is a difference, it is not significant. Do what is more appropriate semantically for the situation.

Comment: @AlexHall I never said the original Method B was good, either. The list comprehension still has to *create* the list, whether or not you assign it to a variable. Never use a list comprehension just for the side effect of calling a function on each element of a list; just use a `for` loop as in Method A.

Comment: Yes, @chepner is right, do not shorten method B as it will create a new list. Instead, you can use a generator expression `for grade in (grade for student.....)` as they are **LAZY** and more efficient in this case(memory efficient).

Answer (score 0):

These have the same time complexity, `O(nm)`, since it's a loop over another loop. So, the `n` is `group.students`, and `m` is `students.grades`. Functionally, these should be the same time complexity too since it's iterating over both lists either way.