# Change Boolean Value Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, boolean

I'm trying to write a code that takes a Boolean value and swaps it for the opposite in a list. So let's say I start out with 100 Falses and want to change every one to True. Then I want to change every other one to False, starting at the second one. I hope that makes sense.

an example would be:

```
>>>False False False False False False False False False False
>>>True True True True True True True True True True
>>>True False True False True False True False True False
>>>True False False False True True True False False True
```

Comment: `python generators` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102535/what-can-you-use-python-generator-functions-for

Comment: What operation is done for the third one to get the fourth? (`True False False False True True True True False True`)

Comment: Sorry, I messed that up

Comment: @WhooCares, Now it change items at indexes of 2, 5, 8, 9.. (3rd, 6th, 9th, 10th) I still don't get it what change rule is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension and slicing:

```
>>> lst = [False] * 10
>>> lst
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
>>> lst[:] = [not x for x in lst]
>>> lst
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
>>> lst[1::2] = [not x for x in lst[1::2]]
>>> lst
[True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False]
```

Comment: How would you do this for large numbers? Say 100? Or 100?

Comment: @WhooCares, This code should work without modification. (except the first `lst = [False] * 10`.

Comment: @WhooCares, If it is really huge, you can use generation expression instead of list comprehension:  `lst[1::2] = (not x for x in lst[1::2])`

Answer (score 0):

Switch every other element to its opposite:

```
my_list = [False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
for index in range(0, len(my_list), 2):
    my_list[index] = not my_list[index]
```

Comment: Fixed it - renamed list[index] to my_list[index].

Comment: Using `range(0, len(my_list), 2)`, you don't need to use `if`.