# Is there a way to only read the header from a csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv, header

I was wondering if there was a way to only read the header info from a csv file without loading the whole file. I'm dealing with large csv files and would rather not have to load the whole thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(filename) as in_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    header = next(csv_reader)
```

This works because `csv.reader()` returns a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102535/what-can-you-use-python-generator-functions-for), not a list. It will only output data if `next()` is called (i.e. by using `next(csv_reader)` or by using it in a for loop, like  `for row in csv_reader`).

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't normally read the whole file anyway. Just create the CSV reader and call `next()` on it once.

```
import csv
f = open('myfile.csv')
reader = csv.reader(f)
header = reader.next()
```