# What is the difference between normal function and generator function?

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to understand the below methodology,

```
In [26]: def generator():
   ....:     print 'generator function hits'
   ....:     for i in range(3):
   ....:         yield i
   ....:         

In [27]: def normal():
   ....:     print 'normal function hits'
   ....:     return range(3)
   ....: 

In [28]: gen = generator()

In [29]: type(gen)
Out[29]: generator

In [30]: fun = normal()
normal function hits

In [31]: type(fun)
Out[31]: list
```

Here my research from the above code,
26 is the `generator()` function and 27 is the `normal()` function, when I have assigned `generator()` function to gen variable I haven't seen any print message like **generator function hits**, But if I have assigned the `normal()` function to fun variable, I have seen the print message like **normal function hits**. My question is `why generator() function not hit ?`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can you use Python generator functions for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102535/what-can-you-use-python-generator-functions-for) (The answers lie in here, even if answered in a longer-winded manner.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a generator function's body is not executed until you call `next` on it.

```
>>> gen = generator()
>>> next(gen)
generator function hits
0
```

Now on the second `next()` call the generator will run again from where it left off:

```
>>> next(gen)
1
```

Answer (score 3):

Generator function stops at yield, next you call again it resumes from where yield stopped. `xrange` is also built-in generator version of `range` function. Since `range` returns list, `xrange` generates numbers on demand, memory efficiency is on the side of `xrange`.