# Python 3.6 cssutils.getUrls error: generator object getUrls

Tags: python

I get a generator object error instead of the css URLs I am trying to extract. Can someone help resolve?

```
>>> import cssutils
>>> cssutils.getUrls('http://4nprofessionals.com/css/style.css')
    <generator object getUrls at 0x000001647F5FC0A0>
>>> css = cssutils.getUrls('http://4nprofessionals.com/css/style.css')
>>> print (css)
    <generator object getUrls at 0x000001647F6B4BF8>
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to convert it to a list with `list()`. A better solution is to read about generators and how to use them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can you use Python generator functions for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102535/what-can-you-use-python-generator-functions-for)

Comment: Thanks. I tried converting to a list and got the following errors:>>> list(css)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#58>", line 1, in <module>
    list(css)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cssutils\__init__.py", line 211, in getUrls
    for importrule in (r for r in sheet if r.type == r.IMPORT_RULE):
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cssutils\__init__.py", line 211, in <genexpr>
    for importrule in (r for r in sheet if r.type == r.IMPORT_RULE):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: This must be an issue with `cssutils`.

Comment: the issue is in line 211 in ini.py inside the cssutils folder: File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages‌​\cssutils_init_.py", line 211, in getUrls for importrule in (r for r in sheet if r.type == r.IMPORT_RULE): File "C:\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-package‌​s\cssutils_init_.py"‌​, line 211, in <genexpr> for importrule in (r for r in sheet if r.type == r.IMPORT_RULE): AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'type'    any thoughts?